# How do I correct this getelementbyclassname error?

Tags: excel, vba

[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPfre.png)

I am trying to get a price from a website, but I keep getting error 91.  My code works accept for it won't select the actual price [number] 0.00014 [highlighted in red in the pic].

It's on this line:
`price = html.getElementsByClassName("sc-be365e-0 bqZvXY").Item(0).innerText`

The class looks correct, so I suspect the error is from this part:
.Item(0).innerText

Help would be greatly appreciated

```
______________________________________
Sub Get_Web_Data()

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant

' Website to go to.
website = "https://app.pulsex.com/info/token/0xa1077a294dde1b09bb078844df40758a5d0f9a27"

' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
request.Open "GET", website, False

' Get fresh data.
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

' Send the request for the webpage.
request.send

' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
html.body.innerHTML = response

' Get the price from the specified element on the page.
**price = html.getElementsByClassName("sc-be365e-0 bqZvXY").Item(0).innerText**

' Output the price.
Range("A1").Value = price

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kECEo.png)

Comment: Most likely the response to that GET request is not the full content as seen in the browser - the page is built dynamically once the initial page is loaded.  You'd need to use (eg) Selenium basic to do this.

Comment: Only using>  CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Answer (score 0):

The website you're using renders everything after loading using JavaScript (React in specific). VBA won't be able to read the page as you see it, as it's just reading the HTML it receives from the request, which is blank.

Instead of using this website, you'd need to find one that has the same information and doesn't require JavaScript to view that information or you could use an API that can get you the information you're after. Two options for the API approach are [CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) and [CoinGecko](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api), which both have APIs to retrieve the information you're after.